# how to debug a pci device and linux driver

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, pci-e

I am programming a pci device with verilog and also writing its driver,
I have probably inserted some bug in the hardware design and when i load the driver with insmod the kernel just gets stuck and doesnt respond. Now Im trying to figure out what's the last driver code line that makes my computer stuck. I have inserted printk in all relevant functions like probe and init but non of them get printed.

What other code is running when i use insmod before it gets to my init function? (I guess the kernel gets stuck over there)

Comment: you can see printed messages in /var/log/messages.

Comment: How is this different from watching dmesg while doing insmod?

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between them.
I thought you didn't do dmesg.

Answer (score 2):

`printk`s are often not useful debugging such a problem.  They are buffered sufficiently that you won't see them in time if the system hangs shortly after `printk` is called.

It is far more productive to selectively comment out sections of your driver and by process of elimination determine which line is the (first) problem.

Begin by commenting out the entire module's `init` section leaving only `return 0;`.  Build it and load it.  Does it hang?  Reboot system, reenable the next few lines (`class_create()`?) and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are telling, it is looks like that Linux scheduler is deadlocking by your driver. That's mean that interrupts from the system timer doesn't arrive or have a chance to be handled by kernel. There are two possible reasons:

- You hang somewhere in your driver interrupt handler (handler starts its work but never finish it).
- Your device creates interrupts storm (Device generates interrupts too frequently as a result your system do the only job -- handling of your device interrupts).
- You explicitly disable all interrupts in your driver but doesn't reenable them.

In all other cases system will either crash, either oops or panic with all appropriate outputs or tolerate potential misbehavior of your device.

I guess that `printk` won't work for such extreme scenario as hang in kernel mode. It is quite heavy weight and due to this unreliable diagnostic tool for scenarios like your.
This trick works only in simpler environments like bootloaders or more simple kernels where system runs in default low-end video mode and there is no need to sync access to the video memory. In such systems tracing via debugging output to the display via direct writing to the video memory can be great and in many times the only tool that can be used for debugging purposes. Linux is not the case.

What techniques can be recommended from the software debugging point of view:

1. Try to review you driver code devoting special attention to interrupt handler and places where you disable/enable interrupts for synchronization.
2. Commenting out of all driver logic with gradual uncommenting can help a lot with localization of the issue.
3. You can try to use remote kernel debugging of your driver. I advice to try to use virtual machine for that purposes, but I'm not aware about do they allow to pass the PCI device in the virtual machine.
4. You can try the trick with in-memory tracing. The idea is to preallocate the memory chunk with well known virtual and physical addresses and zeroes it. Then modify your driver to write the trace data in this chunk using its virtual address. (For example, assign an unique integer value to each event that you want to trace and write '1' into the appropriate index of bytes array in the preallocated memory cell). Then when your system will hang you can simply force full memory dump generation and then analyze the memory layout packed in the dump using physical address of the memory chunk with traces. I had used this technique with VmWare Workstation VM on Windows. When the system had hanged I just pause a VM instance and looked to the appropriate .vmem file that contains raw memory latout of the physical memory of the VM instance. Not sure that this trick will work easy or even will work at all on Linux, but I would try it.
5. Finally, you can try to trace the messages on the PCI bus, but I'm not an expert in this field and not sure do it can help in your case or not.

In general kernel debugging is a quite tricky task, where a lot of tricks in use and all they works only for a specific set of cases. :(

Answer (score 0):

I would put a logic analyzer on the bus lines (on FPGA you could use chipscope or similar). You'll then be able to tell which access is in cause (and fix the hardware). It will be useful anyway in order to debug or analyze future issues.

Another way would be to use the kernel crash dump utility which saved me some headaches in the past. But depending your Linux distribution requires installing (available by default in RH). See http://people.redhat.com/anderson/crash_whitepaper/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really anything that is run before your init. Bus enumeration is done at boot, if that goes by without a hitch the earliest cause for freezing should be something in your driver init AFAIK.

You should be able to see `printk`s as they are printed, they aren't buffered and should not get lost. That's applicable only in situations where you can directly see kernel output, such as on the text console or over a serial line. If there is some other application in the way, like displaying the kernel logs in a terminal in X11 or over ssh, it may not have a chance to read and display the logs before the computer freezes.

If for some other reasons the `printk`s still do not work for you, you can instead have your init function return early. Just test and move the return to later in the init until you find the point where it crashes.

It's hard to say what is causing your freezes, but interrupts is one of those things I would look at first. Make sure the device really doesn't signal interrupts until the driver enables them (that includes clearing interrupt enables on system reset) and enable them in the driver only after all handlers are registered (also, clear interrupt status before enabling interrupts).

Second thing to look at would be bus master transfers, same thing applies: Make sure the device doesn't do anything until it's asked to and let the driver make sure that no busmaster transfers are active before enabling busmastering at the device level.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the kernel gets stuck as soon as you install your driver module makes me wonder if any other driver (built in to kernel?) is already driving the device. I made this mistake once which is why i am asking. I'd look for the string "kernel driver in use" in the output of 'lspci' before installing the module. In any case, your printk's should be visible in dmesg output.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Claudio's suggestion, couple more debug ideas:
1. try kgdb (https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kgdb/EnableKGDB.html)
2. use JTAG interfaces to connect to debug tools (these i think vary between devices, vendors so you'll have to figure out which debug tools you need to the particular hardware)